# Allow SE indexing on index.html only

Tags: seo, search-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

What would be the shortest method to block * and only allow just Major Search Engines to index the index page of the site only?

```
User-agent:  *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
Allow: index.html

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
Allow: index.html

User-agent: msn
Disallow: /
Allow: index.html
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the shortest way to do it.  It's not necessarily correct.

Not all bots support the `Allow` directive.  And some bots are confused about how to interpret the robots.txt when there is both a `User-agent: *` section and a `User-agent: Specific-bot` section that apply.

To be sure it would work, you'd want to do something like this:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /file1
Disallow: /file2
Disallow: /file3
# etc. until you have blocked every path except index.html

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /file1
Disallow: /file2
Disallow: /file3
# etc. until you have blocked every path except index.html

User-agent: msn
Disallow: /file1
Disallow: /file2
Disallow: /file3
# etc. until you have blocked every path except index.html

User-agent:  *
Disallow: /
```

If you don't want to do all that work, then the best thing to do would be to test each of the engine's you're interested in and see if they'll accept the robots.txt file you proposed.  If they don't, try the longer version.